# Video format that will play on MacOS

Tags: rendering, animation, export

I exported my animation with all standard settings and used the 3rd Selection in the Video Format Options. When the render was complete, I couldn’t open it because it was in .mkv. What specific settings should I use for a Mac?

Comment: On a mac youi can use quicktime as a container, and then you can choose from a number of codecs. Depending on the quality you are after, choose DNXHD or ProRes for  high quality or mp4 for compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

You should use FFmpeg video and MPEG-4. It will output a .mp4 file, which is the most common video file format and will probably work on any device, including mac.

[image]